# Make Custom ListView by category

Tags: android, listview, categories

i post here because i dont really know how can i solve my problem.

i've a ListView wich contains Listitems:

ListView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <Button    android:id="@+id/refresh_promo"
                android:text="@string/refresh_promo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Listitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_promotions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#bd0043"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />
    <!-- Description label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/compagny_promotions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip">
    </TextView>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Valable jusqu'au  " />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/availabledate_promotions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#acacac" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left">
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I manage well already displaying item that I recover from my webservice in my ListView but now I would classify this items according to a field that characterize them: String category.

I would like a textview with categories for each item below the correspondents and dont display this textview if there is no item.
And i dont want to use ExpendableListView.
Help me please :$